# Editar Form c/ modal + Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, modal

Boa tarde a todos,

estou implementando um form de editar (modal) que tem um link 'Editar' e que qdo clicado abre um formulario modal. O grande problema eh q nao estou conseguindo assimilar o link 'Editar' e trazer cada linha do BD para o form modal para ser editado. Agradeço desde ja.

```
<h1 class="title"><i class="fa fa-gears fa-2x"></i> PAINEL ADMINISTRATIVO / PRODUTOS </h1>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th>R$ Preço</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                  <?php foreach($prod as $get_prods): ?>
                    <td><?php echo $get_prods->produto; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $get_prods->tipo; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $get_prods->preco; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="#box-editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#box-editar"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i> Editar</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
              </table><br />

        <!-- Modal editar -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="box-editar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="boxLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="boxLabel"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i> Editar Produto</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='' data-dismiss="modal">Salvar alterações</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: o select no bd esta funcionando de boa consigo trazer todas as informaçoes, o grande problema e com o link 'editar' q abre uma modal, nao estou conseguindo assimilar esse link com cada linha q vem do banco pra fazer a ediçao

Answer (score 0):

Você deve montar o form de edição, com os campos ou criar o mesmo no admin, realizar a chamada do modal passando as informações do banco!
ex.:

```js
$('#idDoModalContent').load(base +'index.php/admin/Controller/Method' ,function(result){
  $('#idDoModalContent').html(result);
});
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="idDoModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Resumo do Jogo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="idDoModalContent">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">         
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Fechar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basicamente seria isto!!

Comment: tiago, por eu sou novato e ao msm tempo esta gostando da experiencia de usar o CI olha so oq eu estava tentando fazer (creio eu q isso nao de sucesso), colocando toda a estrutura do modal dentro do foreach e tentando utilizar as mesmas informaçoes do select

Comment: se eu nao conseguir fazer com modal vo ter q fazer sem msm :(

Comment: Pra carregar dados de edição na tela do modal juntamente com a chamada do mesmo, terá q usar Jquery, não tem como fugir disso!